# 403 Forbidden - WAMP Server 2.5

Tags: wampserver

I have installed WAMP version 2.5 on my windows 8.1 machine. When i browse to localhost in my browser, the WAMP server page is visible.

But when I browse to my localhost in my mobile connected to same AP, I get the message  **"403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server"**.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WAMPServer is configured to be a single seat developer tool for the AMP stack on a windows system.

As such and for the security of the complete beginner, WAMPServers Apache is configured to only accept connections from the PC that is running the Apache service.

If you want to connect to Apache from an IP other than that of the PC running WAMPServer, like your phone or another PC on your local network, you have to tell Apache that is allowed.

The simple solution for this is to use the wampmanager menus system :-

```
wampmanager -> Put Online
```

This will change the `httpd.conf` file from

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
```

To

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require all granted
```

Thus allowing any ip address in the universe to connect to your Apache web server. If you are sure that there is no external access to your local network this is reasonable solution.

If however you think that now or at some future time your network may allow access over port 80 from an external source, I prefer to be a little more specific when I change this parameter. So if you prefer you can

Edit the `httpd.conf` file, use the wampmanager menus to do this

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf
```

Then change this

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
```

To

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
Require ip 192.168.1
```

assuming that your local subnet starts with those 3 quartiles and that your phone is connected to your router via WiFi.

If your phone is using your suppliers network i.e. not your WiFi this will not work and you will have to Port Forward your router, but thats another question.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for solutions to resolve the error "Forbidden" with **Wampserver 2.5 in Windows 8.1**.

Here's what I found:

Locate the file: `httpd.conf`
In my case the file is in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf`

The look for the line `<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">`

And then look for the line `Require local`, next write the following:

```
Require all granted
```

Restart your wampserver and you can browse the localhost on every devices that stays connected in your local network.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you try all the above cannot solve, then try this.

I have the same problem then I realize there is **.htaccess** file that blocks the directory listing. Try to remove or reconfigure the .htaccess file.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled the services, almost damage the wampserver.

I tried [this](https://www.digifloor.com/simple-steps-fix-403-forbidden-errors-wamp-server-28), and the section "**Fix 403 Forbidden error on other computer in local network**" worked for me. It was simplier, becuase the issue was in the ‘**httpd-vhosts.conf**’ file.

https://www.digifloor.com/simple-steps-fix-403-forbidden-errors-wamp-server-28